# How to get a 2D Plot from a 3D Listplot?

Tags: plotting

I have the following `ListPlot3D` , where `C` is specific Heat , `T` temperature and `n` concentration, my list first column present `n`, second `T` and third column is for `C`.
I have this code to plot 3D graph from file name "data"

```
data = PadLeft[Import["E:\\new_n\\T(n).dat", "Table"]];
d = ListPlot3D[data, PlotRange -> Full, AxesLabel -> {n, T, C}, 
   PlotStyle -> Green]
```

List in [the link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ZE2wyNWXpLbhqSGBjoNhzv4vWmvqHL37)

Is it possible to get 2D graph from 3d listPlot?  Could you please help me?

Any suggestions are very appreciated.

Comment: How do you want to get the 2D plot? Along which axis? What view point? Can you just project onto the XY plane? Onto the XZ plane? We'll need more info to help you

Comment: @b3m2a1 i want to plot  T(c) plane xy

Comment: Sorry I cannot access data from the link, but `Show[d,ViewPoint->{0,0,Infinity}]` should work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = PadLeft[Import["E:\\new_n\\T(n).dat", "Table"]];
T = data[[All, 2]]; c = data[[All, 3]];
ListPlot[Table[{c[[i]], T[[i]]}, {i, 1, Length[c]}], 
 AxesLabel -> {"c", "T"}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: fig1]

Find the maximum values `c[n,T]` for all `n`:

```
k = 0; j = 0; nn = {1}; Do[
 Do[If[n[[i + j]] == n[[i + j + 1]], k = k + 1, Break[]], {i, j + 1, 
   Length[n]}]; k1 = If[k > Length[n], Length[n], k]; 
 nn = Flatten[{nn, k1}]; If[k >= Length[n] - 1, Break[]];, {100}]
m = {}; Do[
 m = Flatten[{m, 
     MaximalBy[Table[data[[i]], {i, nn[[j]], nn[[j + 1]]}], Last]}, 
    1];, {j, 1, Length[nn] - 1}]
```

Using `m` we find `T[n]`

```
ListPlot[Table[{m[[i, 1]], m[[i, 2]]}, {i, 1, Length[m]}], 
 PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"n", "T"}]
```

[image: fig2]

Comment: Sir @Alex Trounev is there anyway to build it T(n) by selecting maximum value of c every n concentration  automatically , if there any suggest are very appreciated , like in this file in like [Link]( https://drive.google.com/open?id=1sOiO9zR-OL5X5OJ1XdUErfo-Gu5g52vL)

Comment: In your file data `T[n]` with two maximum, I showed how to find one.

Answer (score 4):

You may use [`ListContourPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListContourPlot.html).  Also, you may want to have a look at the [`ColorFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorFunction.html) option of these functions.

With `data` as in OP.  Then

```
ListContourPlot[data,
 PlotRange -> Full,
 FrameLabel -> {n, T},
 PlotLegends -> Automatic,
 ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"StarryNightColors", "Reverse"}]
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope this helps.